# C# Where should my collection of data objects be instantiated?

Tags: c#, oop

I am using C#, but I think this applies to most programming languages.

Philosophical question here. When I write windows form applications, I try very hard to keep UI and data structures separate. But I wonder if I am doing it the best way, OO-wise.

For instance, if I have MyClass, and my application requires many of them, perhaps stored in a List, should I make that List a member of the Form1 (with Form1 being the "main" form)? If not, where should I instantiate the List? Any opinion on public vs. private declaration, or is it just a matter of whatever is needed?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
  private List<MyClass> myClassList; // good idea? Bad idea?

  public Form1 ()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

Comment: How about having it as a property on the form which can be set from outside? Or passing an instance of the list to the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If your list stores things related to the UI, like form controls, then yes, that could probably be the best place for it.

Otherwise, it would depend on the context - which we can't see whole here.

**Edit:** at some point, your form will have to hold a reference to an instance of one of your non UI classes. I think (though again, without more context, can't be 100% sure) that one of these objects should be the one keeping the list.

Try to keep your logic as independent of the form as possible - i.e.: manipulate that list as little as you can from the form, and as much as you can from the non UI classes. You may end up seeing that in the end you don't need the form to hold that reference to the list at all.

**Edit again:** if I have a system for a pet shop, I might have a *Kennel* class and a generic list holding items of the *Pup* class. The kennel instance would hold the list of puppies, not the UI. I hope this small example illustrates my point more clearly.

Comment: No, the collection is not related to the UI. I have created classes to hold all of the data my app needs to store, and I could instantiate them from anywhere. But somehow I think doing that on the UI seems anti-OO. But I can't imagine where else to do it.

Comment: You made an edit after I posted my last comment, so I am starting a new comment here. You said "At some point, your form will have to hold a reference to an instance of one of your non UI classes." and that was the conclusion I came to as well, so I saw no other alternative to doing that in the UI class. In your pet shop example, I think your Form1 would have to instantiate the kennel, but absolutely should not be storing the main list of puppies.

Comment: @MrGibbage exactly. The form holds a reference to the kennel, and the kennel holds a reference to the list of puppies. Notice that form only keeps a kennel so that the kennel will exist as long as the form instnace exists too. I could just instantiate the kennel inside a method, but it would be inacessible as soon as the method exited. This is more common in web applications, where you have an instance of a form for each request made to the application.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about choosing the *scope* of the data and what kinds of operations you are going to be performing on them on the regular basis.  For example, you may want other parts of the program to know about that list, but they might not *have* to know that `Form1` even exists.  Things can also get messy when you start performing operations on that list in a way that doesn't actually concern the `Form1` class.

Whenever you make a new variable, ask yourself some questions.  Do other classes need to know about this variable?  Do I need to perform operations on this variable that are independent of the form?  Does this variable truly **belong** to the form?

Asking yourself these types of questions can save you time in the future and make your program more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

An internal representation of a list of objects isn't bad (though you should have a good reason to waste the extra memory if you only need it to draw a form), but the list (if it is required to meaningfully render the form) should be an argument in the constructor.